# How can I ask sbt-buildinfo to run only at (re)load time and not compile time?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin, sbt-buildinfo

I use the `sbt-buildinfo` SBT plugin, which works great.

I would like to improve the following thing: currently, all values in the generated file can only change if the whole sbt project is reloaded, and thus not at every `compile` run. I would therefore like to prevent `BuildInfo` from being regenerated at compile time, and instead, directly generate it at project load time only.

Is this possible?

Comment: I tried with sbt-buildinfo 0.5.0. It's not going to regenerate on every compile, unless the generated file is removed or modified. Is there something that modifies the generated source file silently? Scalariform, for example.

Comment: No, nothing is modifying it AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad. `sbt-buildinfo` is smarter than I am… It indeed doesn't regenerate the file if it doesn't need to. In my case, it was regenerating it because I ad added the `BuildInfoOption.BuildTime` option, which adds the build time to `BuildInfo`, and which causes the regeneration.